# Retrieve Text from String where Start and End Characters are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get the text between the **** stars considering the begin and end are the same string values?

```
Create Table #temp
(
    TestString varchar(400)
)

insert into #temp
(
    TestString
)
select
    '**** mary had a little lamb****'
union
select
    '**** humpy dumpty had a great fall**** All the king''s horses and all the king''s men'
```

Comment: is it going to be **** always ? if yes, then you can compare first 4 char and last 4 char using SUBSTR, if same then use REPLCE() to replace * with ''.

Comment: Yes, it will always be the text between **** and ****.  I can't compare the last 4 chars because it won't always be the last 4 chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the base string functions as follows:

```
SELECT
    TestString,
    SUBSTRING(TestString,
              CHARINDEX('****', TestString) + 4,
              CHARINDEX('****', TestString, CHARINDEX('****', TestString) + 1) - 5) AS contents
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

**Data:**

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '**** mary had a little lamb****' AS TestString UNION ALL
    SELECT '**** humpy dumpty had a great fall**** All the king''s horses and all the king''s men'
)
```

Comment: I'll create a new question if that's best, but I totally forgot about this situation. Is there an easy solution? - SELECT 'bla **** abcd two two **** dfdfdfd'